# How do I distribute data files with a python package such that they're readable?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I have a python module with a setup like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup = (
    ...
    package_data={'mypackage': ['my/file.data']})
```

in a package laid out like this:

```
mypackage/
    setup.py
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        my/
            file.data
```

and `__init__.py` looks something like this:

```
import pkgutil
DATA = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, 'my/file.data')
```

Pretty simple. All I want is to get some data into my python plugin. However, when I install it with

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

and try to run it, I get

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypackage/my/file.data'
```

It's been installed with incorrect permissions.

How do I distribute data and config files in python such that they can be read at runtime?

Comment: The file probably has the wrong permissions, make sure that the .data file can be read by everyone.

Comment: It certainly has the wrong permissions. The question is how to make `setup.py install` install it with the correct permissions, as I don't have the capabilities to change the `.data` file permissions on the machine of everyone who installs my package.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid you can’t do that out of the box: if I recall correctly file permissions are just copied as is.  You’d need to write a custom build command to change the file rights in the build directory before they are copied by the install command.

The simplest solution would be to have the desired rights in your repository or source tree.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem and I solve it.

As @Éric Araujo said, you should change the pemission of your `file.data`.
If the permission of your file is `400`, it will be also installed with permission `400`. But the owner will be `root` if you installed the package using `root` permission. And this can't be read by normal users.

I think it will be enough to change the permission to `644`. And remember to delete `mypackage.pkg-info`, `build` and `dist` in your currnet location, or you can't apply the new permission of your data file.